# xml/xslt parsing table layout

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to parse a xml file and put the nodes on a horizontal order; however, since my level is (very) beginner, all my approaches failed; what I could achieve is a "normal" table with all xml elements.

files are [here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/uPLmzm) - xmlplayground

What I would like to achieve is

```
PROD | HOST 1| HOST 2 | HOST 3 | HOST 4 |
disk | value | value  | value  | value  |
etc..| ...   |   ...  |   .... | ...    |
INTE | HOST 5| HOST 6 | HOST 7 |
etc..| value | value  | value  |
TEST | HOST 8|
 etc | values|
```

any hints are appreciated; thanks

#

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="systatus.xsl"?>
<systatus>
<environment name="prod">
  <node name="HOST 1">
    <OS>
         <disk> Total 197G </disk>
         <disk> Use% 29% </disk>
         <ip> 192.168.169.193/24 bond0 </ip>
         <osver> RHEL </osver>
         <kernel> 2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64 </kernel>
         <TotalMemory> 15939 </TotalMemory>
         <package> java-1.6.0-sun-devel-1.6.0.45-1jpp.1.el6.x86_64 </package>
         <package> tomcat6-el-2.1-api-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch </package>
         <package> httpd-2.2.15-26.el6.x86_64 </package>
         <package> java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.45-1jpp.1.el6.x86_64 </package>
         <package> java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0-29.1.el6.x86_64 </package>
         <package> tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch </package>
         <package> tomcat6-jsp-2.1-api-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch </package>
         <package> tomcat6-lib-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch </package>
         <package> httpd-tools-2.2.15-26.el6.x86_64 </package>
         <package> jakarta-commons-httpclient-3.1-0.7.el6_3.x86_64 </package>
         <package> java_cup-0.10k-5.el6.x86_64 </package>
         <package> tomcat6-6.0.24-52.el6_4.noarch </package>
    </OS>
    <App>
         <MinMemory> 4000 </MinMemory>
         <MaxMemory> 8000 </MaxMemory>
         <app_version> 5.5.0 </app_version>
         <module> -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 618184 Aug  9 12:20 mod_module.so </module>
    </App>
  </node>
```

.............

and

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="environment">
<html>
<body>
<h2><b><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b></h2>

<table border="1">

<xsl:for-each select="node">

        <td bgcolor="#9acd32" colspan="2"><b>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" /></b>
        </td>
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
                <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
                </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>



</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Rather than just linking to the files, please could you edit your question to include a suitable sample of the input, your current XSLT, and the desired output inline in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a pivot table from a tree structure, not really an easy thing to do. We can make a simplifying assumption, that every `node` has the particular details you are trying to capture, that will allow us to do some brute force stuff.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="systatus">
    <html>
    <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="environment">
    <xsl:variable name="env">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="$env"/></h2>

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th bgcolor="#9acd32"><xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$env"/></xsl:text></th>
            <xsl:for-each select="node">
                <th bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Disk</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="OS/disk"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>IP</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="OS/ip"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>OS Version</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="OS/osver"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Kernel</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="OS/kernel"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Total Memory</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="node">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="OS/TotalMemory"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A more elegant (i.e., general) solution requires a two-stage process whereby you build a matrix of values and then display the matrix.

Comment: I don't think you need a matrix as the code creates the matrix properly (my mistake). I ran a couple of tests. The above code will work properly even if you don't have an element attached to one of the nodes. You can test for yourself by (temporarily) deleting `osver` from one of the nodes and see that you get a blank cell. You would need a matrix if you wanted a solution that did not wire in the expected rows, such as `disk` and `osver`. As long as they are explicitly selected, the matrix is properly created.

Comment: I'm not familiar with xmlplayground -- did you change the code? Or did someone else? I copied and pasted my code above from Eclipse after running the tests.

Comment: the only difference is that on xmlplayground the xml is complete, here I pasted only the first node. I shall get Eclipse and see it through. Thanks